# Best practice for passing through generator function in JS

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, generator, yield

I am trying to figure out the best practice of passing a generator (including yield) function through another function as is.

In other words, I am looking for a better way to achieve the following.

Let's say that I have class `ServiceA` and `ServiceB`, that own the same method `generate`, that generates some sequences:

```
class ServiceA extends ServiceBase {
    // ...

    * generate() {
        const length = Math.round(Math.rand() * 100);
        for (let i=0; i<length; i++)
            yield i;
        return -1;
    }

    // ...
}

class ServiceB extends ServiceBase {
    // ...

    * generate() {
        const length = Math.round(Math.rand() * 100) + 100;
        for (let i=100; i<length; i++)
            yield i;
        return 13;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Now, I have a wrapper class `ServiceName` that uses class `ServiceA` or `ServiceB`, but also, passing through the `generate` method from these classes:

```
class ServiceManager {
    #service;

    constructor(serviceName) {
        // The following require will return ServiceA or ServiceB instance
        this.#service = require('./service/' + serviceName);
    }

    * generate() {
        for ( let i of this.#service.generate() )
            yield i;
    }

    // ...
}
```

And extension is not an option, as this is a design pattern I need.

**Two questions regarding the `generate` method within class `ServiceManager`:**

1. How do I passthrough a `return` in addition to `yield`?
2. Is there a better and more clean way to implement it?

Comment: `#service` doesn't look like ES6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. How do I passthrough a `return` in addition to `yield`?

```
* generate() {
    return yield* this.service.generate();
}
```

> 2. Is there a better and more clean way to implement it?

```
generate() {
    return this.service.generate();
}
```

> ```
>     #service;
> ```

```
this.#service = …
```

```
return this.#service.generate();
```